# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for Jewish life and learning
- interesting in-site activities and events
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3353).

Comment: @OldBunny2800, I just saw one of these '15 ones, so I guess they're still live. That said, the '16 ones are live also (according to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3850), so I don't know what's going on....

Answer (score 14):

[image: HebrewBooks.org]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Sefaria: A Living library of Jewish texts]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Hebrew Language]

Comment: How did you get around the Imgur requirement?

Comment: It appears that they don't actually enforce it. And even if they do, Area51 is whitelisted.

Comment: Hmm. I ask because I tried stealing this ad for Christianity.SE and it didn't even allow me to submit.

Comment: Has this ad for sure been spotted on Mi.Yodeya?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I *think* it has, but i'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Never mind, [it has for sure](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3353).

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude FYI, this proposal has moved to the Commitment phase.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Magically convert a citation into a link on Mi Yodeya.]

Comment: I'll just steal this for 2017, if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Mi Yodeya Publications]

Answer (score 7):

[Current Mi Yodeya bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/judaism.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: Copied from [Physics.SE](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/6398#6398), first mentioned by [Shokhet in Bam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19349954#19349954).

Answer (score 6):

[image: @mi_yodeya]

Comment: I stole this answer from [last year's answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2015/5323), which stole the image from the other ad for the robot-curated twitter feed.

Comment: Thief!‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪

Answer (score -2):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Y'all have your own curated Twitter account as well, keep in mind.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Hi bleh. Note that this thread is for links for 2015 (which is fast ebbing away). In all likelihood a new one will come out soon for future ads and you would have to repost.

Comment: I'll do that, just posting it here for now.